# Average of unknown numbers in JAVA

Tags: java, average

I am looking for the perfect numbers from 1 to 10000 and the arithmetic average of the results. The code below provides the perfect numbers (6, 28, 496, 8128 ) but cannot find solution for their average.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int min = 1; 
int max = 10000;

for (min = 1; min <= max; min++) { 
    int sum = 0;
    for (int e = 1; e < min; e++) {
        if ((min % e) == 0) {
            sum += e;
        } 
    }  
    if (sum == min){           
        System.out.println(sum);
    }          
}
```

}

Comment: Hello Backlash, welcome to SO! When asking for the "average of the output" what exactly do you mean? "Average" most likely means "arithmetic mean", right? My guess is "output" refers to the sum of all `e` with `min % e == 0`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, I need the average of the output (6, 28, 496, 8128). The problem for me is that theoretically, I don't know what numbers the code will provide, so I can't define the sum and number of the numbers beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate average of result you can do using streams:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int min = 1;
    int max = 10000;

    List<Integer> avg = new ArrayList<>();

    for (min = 1; min <= max; min++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int e = 1; e < min; e++) {
            if ((min % e) == 0) {
                sum += e;
                avg.add(e);
            }
        }
        if (sum == min) {
            System.out.println(sum);
        }

    }
    
    //Rounded average result:
    System.out.println("The result average is: " + Math.round(avg.stream()
                                                       .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                                                       .average()
                                                       .getAsDouble()));
    
    //Or not rounded average result with two digits precision:
    System.out.printf("The result average is: %.2f \n", avg.stream()
                                                         .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                                                         .average()
                                                         .getAsDouble());       
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time that I did something in Java but that should do the trick. An average is the sum of all elements divided by the number of elements. So, what we need is a counter to count all the elements that go into sum and divide it at then end.

```
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args){
int min = 1; 
int max = 10; // reduced max for testing
int count = 0;
double average;

    for (min = 2; min <= max; min++) { // start loop at 2
        int sum = 0;
        count = 0;
        for (int e = 1; e < min; e++) {
            if ((min % e) == 0) {
                sum += e;
                count = count +1;
            } 
        }
        if(count == 0) { // catch problems if count == 0
          System.out.println(min);
          average = -1;
        }
        else
          average = sum / count;
        System.out.println(average);
        if (sum == min){
            System.out.println(sum);
        }          
    }      
}}
```

Comment: Thnak you. I've forgotten to mention that it is JAVA. I've tried the suggested code but got back this error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Comment: I guess, the problem is that the value of the count is 0 since we use it out of the 2nd for cycle where it doesn't keep the value we need.

Comment: I did some checking. It only does't work in the first iteration. Skip that and it works. A scoping issue was unlikely anyway. I do not know any programming language that defines scope in the basis of loops.

Comment: Or change the condition in the for-loop. If the loop is only entered while `e < min`and both values are one, the code skips the loop completely and `count` is still 0.

Comment: Thanks, Jan. I made the description of he problem more precised. Hopefully,  that clarifies the issue I am facing.